# Use query as conditional split expression in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl, conditional-split

How to use the query below in conditional split , `nxdt` is a date column; it has  values like `11/30/0002 00:00:00.000000`. Hence used below query to filter out and need to use the same in my package

```
SELECT *
FROM VLCVehicle 
WHERE  DATEPART(year, nxtDt) < '1753' OR DATEPART(year, nxtDt) > '9999'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following expression:

```
 DATEPART("yyyy", [nxtDt]) < 1753 || DATEPART("yyyy", [nxtDt]) > 9999
```